# SELECT one column where condition is met

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this :

```
ID  Name_1            Name_2               Name_3
1   Egon Spengler     Ives Dertway         Blade Ketlump
2   Mac Taylor        Jedidiah Buckbolt    Sarah Connor
3   Sarah Connor      Modesto Slowfell     Jean-Luc Picard
4   Jean-Luc Picard   Beulah Cuxpan        Henry Jones
5   Ellen Ripley      Adeline Finkdell     Ives Dertway
6   James T. Kirk     Bertram Cam          Mac Taylor 
7   Henry Jones       Vidal Matton         Bertram Cam
```

There is never same name in all three of the columns, so this cannot happen :

```
3   Sarah Connor      Sarah Connor     Sarah Connor
```

I would like to Select just one name which meets the condition LIKE = '%value%',
Problem is I never know which row to select exactly and I don't want to select them all.
People in this table are authors. There are also column about title of book, genre and so on.
I want to do search only in authors of the books.

Thank you for your help...

Comment: I would just do an OR and then check each column in whatever language you're using.  Also, what is the end goal of this?  At first glance, if this is how you're using the data, your table may be structured wrong.

Comment: After your edit, you should definitely alter your structure.  What if a book has 4 authors?  Are you going to add another column.  Look into one to many relationships and normalization.

Comment: yes.. but it almost never happens that there are more than 3 authors of my books. I have mostly 1 or 2 per book. What structure are you proposing ? Should authors be in other table ?

Comment: Basically what liquorvicar suggested at the end of his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've got your data structured you can just do

```
SELECT [row info you need]
FROM `table`
WHERE Name_1 LIKE '%value%'
   OR Name_2 LIKE '%value%'
   OR Name_3 LIKE '%value%'
```

Or by using a full-text index (you would need to create the index first):

```
SELECT [row info you need]
FROM `table`
WHERE MATCH( names ) AGAINST ( 'value' )
```

Obviously using either of these won't tell you which column has matched.

But you might be better off redesigning your schema like this

```
table
-----
id
[other info]

names
-----
id
name

tables_names
------------
table_id
name_id
```

That way you could do a simple INNER JOIN and avoid having the separate OR clauses and you will be able to tell which value has matched your query very easily.

Comment: so now I have :
   book - id(pri), name1, name2, name3, title
| I should have:
   book - id(pri), authors_id, title |
   authors - authors_id, author |

Comment: @Simon That would work if you have one and only one author per book. If you have multiple authors you need a books_authors table ("tables_names" in my example).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT

IF (
    Name_1 LIKE '%value%',
    Name_1,
    IF (
        Name_2 LIKE '%value%',
        Name_2,
        IF (
            Name_3 LIKE '%value%',
            Name_3,
            NULL
        )
    )
) AS `Name`

FROM
    Table_Name
WHERE
    Name_1 LIKE '%value%' OR Name_2 LIKE '%value%' OR Name_3 LIKE '%value%'
```

Comment: Had to update a typo: `AD \`Name\`` Should have been `AS \`Name\``, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Without refactoring structure of table you cant do much, the only possible way is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name_1 LIKE '%xx%' or Name_2 LIKE '%xx%' OR Name_3 LIKE '%xx%'
```